# Подскажите, как правильно сформировать правило для редиректа через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно все запросы, которые выглядят как:

```
домен/wp-content/cache/all/что-угодно/index.html
```

перенаправлять на:

```
домен/что-угодно/
```

То есть нужно срезать после домена `/wp-content/cache/all/` и в конце `index.html`

Добавил такое

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/cache/all/(.*)$ //$1 [L,R=301]
```

Не понимаю, как при этом добавить еще удаление index.html

Comment: почему у вас в правиле два паттерна?

Comment: RewriteRule ^wp-content/cache/all/(.*)$ //$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: вот, рабочий вариант, но не знаю как при этом убрать index.html в конце

Comment: `^wp-content/cache/all/(.*?)/index.html$` /$1`  поиск просто надо не жадный делать, и индекс добавить к строке.

Comment: я ваш сленг не понял

Comment: RewriteRule ^wp-content/cache/all/(.*)$ //$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index\.html$ 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/ [R=301,L]

Сделал таким образом, но тут выходит два редиректа, как объединить правила?

Comment: в моем комменте выше приведено правило, не работает, или что?

Comment: а есть))) не заметил, все отлично, спасибо

Comment: оформил ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

обычный поиск `.*` называется "жадным": в это выражение попадет все до конца строки (максимально возможно по длине совпадение). Но поскольку нам требуется наличие еще и `index.html` в конце, то это нужно просто дописать к шаблону. При этом алгоритм лучше сменить на нежадный (минимальное совпадение), обеспечивается это добавлением знака вопроса после звездочки - `.*?`, таким образом искомое выражение будет иметь вид:

```
 RewriteRule ^wp-content/cache/all/(.*?)/index\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```